# PHP File Operation

Tags: php

I am trying to create a text file with PHP in `fopen("test.txt","a")`. I have also tried with `fopen("test.txt","w+")`.

The text file is created but I want to check for some string in test.text, that it exist or in test.txt it will not create duplicate entry. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$content = file_get_contents('test.txt');
if (str_pos('YOUR KEYWORD', $content) !== false){
// your keyword exists in the file
}
```

Comment: my problem is test.txt contains duplicate value for first value. then others are fine cam u explain me how we can do that

Comment: What do u mean by 'duplicate value for first value'?

Comment: see i have array first value from like ex.array[0] written in file twice except first value all fine how can we stop dat?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!file_exists("test.txt"))
{
    ///file does not exist
}
else
{
    $f = fopen("test.txt", "a"); 
    fwrite($f, "appending text");
}
```

searching in file:

```
$arr = file_get_contents("test.txt");
if (preg_match("/your_rexexp/i", $arr))
{
     echo "text found";
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, it looks fine to me, what's supposed to be PHP 5 specific about it?

Comment: Who's using PHP4 when PHP5 was released 2004-07-13?

Comment: I also did not get it. Thanks @Keoki

Comment: @genesis by the way, I don't think PHP 5 was released back in 2004, I think it was released only within the last year or two or three...but I could be wrong.  Also, people might still want to use PHP 4 because they don't want to spend the time and money to upgrade their codebase to PHP 5, it might be too expensive for them.

Comment: Ahh I didn't realise that file_get_contents has been around since 4.3, though its file_put_contents which is new.

Some shared hosting providers still might still use php4 by default. 1&1 did until very recently.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to insert new values into a textfile, but first check if the value already exists in it.

You can use [fread()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to get the contents of the file, and then through [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you can check for values in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP5 then you can use some of the new easy functions.

`file_exists(filename)` returns boolean
 sayin if the file exists.
`file_put_contents(filename,data)` returns boolean saying if the write was successful.
`file_get_contents(filename)` returns the contents of the file (string).